# Make a UIView relayout itself when dependent constraint changes

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIImageView` and `UIButton`, `UIButton` is aligned to top of `UIImageView`. Now in code I am changing the top of `UIImageView` but the `UIButton` is not updated accordingly. I tried `SetNeedsLayout`, `LayoutIfNeeded` on `UIButton` but nothing works.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    profileImageView.frame.origin.y = arcView.bounds.height/1.8
    editProfileButton.layer.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

I have set the constraints in Storyboard. I would really appreciate any help here.

Comment: Have a look at Ahmad's answer and make sure to call `layoutIfNeeded` for the `UIView` containing **both** the views whose positions you will be changing. Example: `view.layoutIfNeeded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First: Are you sure that all your constraints (for both the UIImageview and UIButton) are added right?
- Second: when working the constraints, you should change the `origin.y` of the UIImageview also by by a constraint, by modifying its [constant](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1526928-constant)'s value:

Instead of directly changing `profileImageView.frame.origin.y`, you should change the `constant` of the constraint that tells what's the imageview `origin.y` (if the first point is applied, this constraint must be exist...); Add this constraint to the viewController as an *IBOutlet* and change value of its `constant` property (take a look at the comments in the code snippet, it's a part of the answer):

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // let's assume that this is the @IBOutlet of the constraint, I called it 'imageViewTopMargin':
    @IBOutlet weak var imageViewTopMargin: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // it's not necessary -for sure- to do this the in the viewDidLoad method
        // but I'm doing this for demo purposes:

        // let's say that you want to push the imageView to the bottom with extra 40 points:
        imageViewTopMargin.constant += 40
    }
}
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks, I just took a reference of the constraint of the UIImageView and it worked. Thanks.....